# Wala Building Error

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ibm-watson

While trying to run first wala example by following steps [here](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/UserGuide:Getting_Started), I am receiving an error [image: error]. However I have copied the JLex.jar in root folder of eclipse work-space.

Comment: Have you tried using the wala group ?

Answer (score 2):

Copy JLex.jar to com.ibm.wala.core.testdata project. Your error will disappear